# index a list of tensors

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a list object named " imgs " of tensors (50 images).
I have an array of indices (indi) of length 29.

how do I index the list of tensors with the array of indices?

when I do the following I get:

```
imgs[indi] 

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are normal python lists then you can use a list comprehension

```py
result = [imgs[i] for i in indi]
```

which will give a list of tensors.

If you further want to make this a single tensor containing the images you can use `torch.stack`

```py
result = torch.stack([imgs[i] for i in indi], dim=0)
```